# Did Tomi Arayomi predict Russia would invade Ukraine, Trump's second impeachment, and Benjamín Netanyahu being removed from governance in 2021?

Tags: divination

In this [YouTube video, dated Jan 5th, 2021](https://youtu.be/rCDFYw9bkDo?t=1060), at the 17:41-18:04 mark,  Tomi Arayomi, [author and pastor](https://www.prophets.org.uk/2019/10/tomi-arayomi-2/) of the [My Church, in Windsor, England](https://propheticvoice.com/mychurch-windsor/) makes some [predictions](https://ucdigitals.online/tomi-arayomis-prophecy-for-2021/) [hat-tip for the link: @Schwern]

> "2021 shall be the year of hastening the Lord says - They will cry China, Ukraine, impeach 46."

He then later on says that "the Lord will shake Benjamin Netanyahu."

If you look at the events he says, it happened: Russia invaded Ukraine, then Trump was impeached almost a week after the video, and Benjamin Netanyahu was removed from governance in 2021.

Is this evidence of supernatural powers? Is this some sort of fluke?

Comment: Please understand that, due to the requirements for *empirical* evidence, there is no way that an answer here can conclude that it is a supernatural power. I predict that won't be a problem in this case.

Comment: Saying "it's not a stopped clock thing" and the listing a single example of a prophecy which came true is nonsensical - the whole point of talking about "stopped clocks" is that cherry-picking a single example that happened to be correct doesn't prove anything. As such, I've removed that paragraph, leaving the question focussing on the claims actually quoted.

Comment: People had been calling for Trump to be impeached practically before he even took office in 2016, and they continued throughout his presidency.  Russia and Ukraine were on a war footing as of 2014.  China became a nuclear power in the 1960s.  None of these "predictions" from 2021 sound that amazing.

Answer (score 9):

## No.

The video is from Jan 4th, 2021. The claim contains keywords available in the news at the time. The claims contain no detail.

One simple way to check if the claims are headline word salad is to do a [web search limited to the months just prior to the new year](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Benjamin+Netanyahu&t=ffab&atb=v344-1&df=2020-10-01..2020-12-31&ia=web) and see if these issues were already in the news.

### Something something something Ukraine

There is only one mention of Ukraine, no mention of Russia, no mention of a war, and no date. Ukraine was in the news due to the [War in Donbas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_Donbas_(2014%E2%80%932022)#October_2019_Steinmeier_formula_agreement_and_July_2020_ceasefire) and Russian interference.

[Russia invaded Ukraine in 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine), not 2021.

### <strike>Trump's</strike> Biden's Impeachment

"Impeach 46"... Trump was the 45th US President. Then US President-Elect Biden would be the 46th. [Republicans were already talking about impeaching Biden](https://www.mediamatters.org/sean-hannity/sean-hannity-floats-impeachment-joe-biden-how-do-you-not-impeach-if-its-joe-biden-one) before he even took office as retribution for impeaching Trump and [Hunter Biden's laptop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter_Biden_laptop_controversy).

### Benjamin Netanyahu, already shaken

> ‘Pray for Israel’, says the Lord, ‘Pray for her! For all her allies will shrink back; and the guard that was holding her will retreat. For a betrayal is on the horizon. A changing of the guard is at hand. Netanyahu shall be shaken, and there will be those who will push for it in the name of secularism. But if my church will pray, I will roar as a lion’.

[Netanyahu's government had just collapsed on Dec 22nd, 2020](https://www.cnn.com/2020/12/22/middleeast/israel-government-collapses-intl/index.html). Most of the Netanyahu paragraph is generic.

## Cherry Picking

As always, reading prediction claims are prone to cherry picking, and data fitting. One can pick and choose only the claims which turned out to bear a resemblance to reality, and one can stretch the claim to match events. For example, "*they will cry, “China, Ukraine, impeach 46”.*" turns into "he predicted the Ukraine war".

1. What did they actually claim?
2. What else did they claim?

Let's look at prediction #10 as a whole.

> 10. 2021 SHALL BE THE YEAR OF HASTING
>
> The Lord says that ‘Your enemy will speed up automation. “Bankrupt! Bankrupt! We are bankrupt”, many will cry. Your economy shall be offset, “Impeach 46”, they will cry, “China, Ukraine, impeach 46”. China asset depose– A great betrayal– An emboldened BLM movement to show their true colors, and it will not be black. Censorship and banning of world leaders– A great push to police the internet, in the name of countering cyber bullying but really censorship in disguise. Draconian policies and unjust arrests; civil disobediences, and the shakings will continue. Many will say, “The shaking is at an end”, I will say, “The shaking will not end in 2020 or 2021. I will shake and shake”’.
>
> And the Lord says,’ I will make you a salt; and I will be the salt shaker, until everything that can be shaken, is shaken. I will shake every manufactured thing, every manufactured Church, relationship, ministry, tradition. For I will build a house’, says the Lord, ‘A house not made with human hands. This will carry the seed of my revelation, and will prioritize it above bread and what satisfies the stomach. They will cry, “When will the shaking end?” And I will say, “When you are unshakeable”’.

And the claims...

- Your enemy will speed up automation.
- “Bankrupt! Bankrupt! We are bankrupt”, many will cry. Your economy shall be offset
- “Impeach 46”, they will cry, “China, Ukraine, impeach 46”
- China asset depose.
- A great betrayal
- An emboldened BLM movement to show their true colors, and it will not be black.
- Censorship and banning of world leaders– A great push to police the internet, in the name of countering cyber bullying but really censorship in disguise.
- Draconian policies and unjust arrests; civil disobediences, and the shakings will continue.
- Many will say, “The shaking is at an end”, I will say, “The shaking will not end in 2020 or 2021. I will shake and shake”’.
- I will shake every manufactured thing, every manufactured Church, relationship, ministry, tradition...

Much of this is vague nonsense, or generic continuations of the existing issues in late 2020.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was in the process of writing, except to point out as I did in the comments that "Impeach 46" would not refer to Trump anyway, it would refer to Biden. Either it's a weird mistake, or they were actually referring to [opposing theories linking *Biden* to Ukraine](https://apnews.com/article/us-news-ap-top-news-elections-international-news-donald-trump-893415ed7acb069604566149630abdb8), and predicting/hoping that *he* would be impeached later in the year. The negative reference to Black Lives Matter shortly afterwards suggests a right-wing/Trumpist political stance.

Comment: @IMSoP Ha, I didn't catch that. I will edit.

Comment: @Schwern I do not know if this is allowed but I was going through his,other prophecy’s and on Early 2020 he prophesied that a Supreme Court judge will leave and in Sep 18 2020 he said roe v wade will be overturned <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MC8Is1_4mdQ>

Comment: @steamguy I don't think it will be productive to keep picking new examples and saying "but what about..." If there's a prediction with a really strong case, it might be worth a new question, but my guess is most will fall into the same old categories: too predictable to need supernatural explanation, too vague to be real predictions, or cherry picking one success from a long string of failures - i.e. dumb luck.

Comment: @steamguy In the final months of 2019, [Roe v Wade was already in question](https://www.nbcnews.com/think/opinion/supreme-court-s-new-abortion-case-shows-roe-v-wade-ncna1063361) and [RBG was already having health problems](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/ruth-bader-ginsburg-hospitalized-chills-fever). 1) Please avoid using highlight videos, we need to see the full predictions. 2) Please check the claims on your own, I like to do [a web search limited to the last few months of the previous year](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ruth+bader+ginsburg&t=ffab&atb=v344-1&df=2019-10-01..2019-12-31&ia=web).

Comment: @steamguy Given that even the highlighted claims of prophesy were all flat-out wrong, I don't see any value in continuing to investigate more claims from him.